# Why does calculating the return on a portfolio differ when calculated at a stock level rather than at a portfolio level?

Tags: summation, inner-products, finance, products

I have a portfolio of three assets A, B and C, each with a beginning value of 100. I trade the portfolio over two days. On day 1, asset A returns 50, B returns 20, and C returns -10. On day two, A returns 0, B returns 0, and C returns 30. These are dollar returns.

When I calculate the returns of each stock over each day, the contribution to return as a percentage of the portfolio's beginning value is right. So, on day 1, A returns 50% (50/300), B returns 20% and C returns -3.3%. And on day two, A returns 0%, B gives 0% and C gives -8.3% (-30/(150+120+90)).

The return of the portfolio for two days is 10%. The profit in dollar terms is 30, and the daily return for the portfolio is 20% on day 1 and -8.3% on day two, which compounds to 10% using the time weighted rate of return. But, if I calculate the returns for each stock and then sum those returns (as a percentage), it does not add up. So, for stock A the return is 16.7%, B gives 6.7%, and C gives -11.4%, and these sum to 11.9%. Why does 11.9% differ from 10%, and what is the right way to adjust my stock level returns to match the 10% of the portfolio? Please see below the screenshot of the daily calculation. Essentially, the cells highlighted in green should sum up to the blue cell. In the picture below, Opening NAV = value of each stock at the beginning of day, Weight = weight of each stock in the portfolio at beginning of day, PnL = profit of each stock for the day, %ctr 1 = the stock's contribution to return of the portfolio (PnL divided by the value of the portfolio at the beginning of day).
[Portfolio returns over two days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7BCv.png)

Edit: Please see a clarification of the problem below.

So at the end of day 1 the market value of A is 150, B is 120, and C is 90. Then on day two A has a profit of zero (the stock price doesn't move), B has a profit of zero, and C has a profit of -30. So the market values of A,B, and C at the end of day two are 150, 120, and 60 respectively. The returns of A,B and C for day two are 0% (0/360), 0% (0/120), and -8.3% (-30/360). So, over two days, what is the return of the portfolio? The return of the portfolio on day 1 is 60/300 (20%), and on day two it is -30/360 (-8.3%). So the return for the portfolio for the entire period is (1+20%)*(1-8.3%)-1 = 10%. This is the time weighted rate of return formula and makes sense because your closing NAV is 330 and you began with 300 so you made 10%. BUT, AT A STOCK LEVEL, WHAT WAS YOUR RETURN OVER THE TWO DAY PERIOD? For stock A, I calculate (1+16.7%)*(1+0%)-1 = 16.7%, For B, I calculate (1+6.7%)*(1+0%)-1 = 6.7%, and then for C I calculate (1-3.3%)*(1-8.3%)-1 = -11.4%. If I sum 16.7%+6.7%-11.4% = 12%. This differs from my portfolio return of 10%!

Edit: The key part of the question is to link the stock level returns to the portfolio return over multiple periods. So, if I have a portfolio total return of 10% over multiple periods, how do the stocks contribute to that return ie stock A contributed 9%, B contributed 5% and c contributed -4% ie 9% + 5% - 4% = 10%.

Comment: Basicllly  the average return as a percentage in n periods is calculated with the geometric mean. And then you take the n-th power to get the total growth in percentage. So the growth factor of C in two periods is $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{90}{100}\cdot \frac{60}{90}}\right)^2=0.6=60\%$$. Therefore the growth rate $0.6-1=-0.4=40\%$. Consecutive growth rates are never summed up.

Comment: What's with the inconsistent arithmetic? On day 1, A indeed *returns* $50\% = \frac {50}{100}$, but its impact on your portfolio is $16.7\% = \frac{50}{300}$. Similarly B has a $20\%$ return, and a $6.7\% = \frac{20}{300}$ impact. But C has a $-10\% = \frac{-10}{100}$ return, and a $-3.3\% = \frac{-10}{300}$ impact on your portfolio. Don't compare A and B's return on investment to C's impact on your porfolio. Those are different things.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you paul, please see the EDIT in the original post at the bottom. Is the question clearer now?

Comment: Hi @callculus thank you. but if i do that for A, B, and C it does not add up to my portfolio total return which is the problem. at the end of the two days, I have 330 whereas i started with 300 so i have a return of 10% = (1+20%)*(1-8.3%) - 1. But if I use your method for A, B and C and then sum up the returns for the stocks, I get 50% + 20% - 40% = 30% return for A, B and C, which does not add up to my portfolio total return. I've also added an EDIT at the bottom of the question which clarifies the question.

Comment: To calculate the growth rate of the portfolio you have to use the values of  the portfolio. So you are right with your calculation. I´ve posted an answer. I hope it helps to make the situation more clear.

Comment: Hi @callculus thank you for the answer. it is so close and i'm so happy that you understand most of the question. But the key key key key question is not only how to calculate the return of the portfolio, but how to *disaggregate that return into the contribution of each security*. Ie, for the portfolio's return, what percentage of the portfolio's return came from stock A, what percentage of the portfolios return came from stock B, and from stock C. That is the key question the investment manager needs answered. He knows what his portfolio return is, but needs to break it down by each stock.

Comment: Percentages do not behave the way you expect because the depend on what you are taking a percentage of.  You need to be very clear about the base to get proper results.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a portfolio of 3 assets ($A,B,C$) and $2$ days. Firstly you calculate the $\textrm{growth factor}$ of the first day of the portfolio, from time $0$ to time $1$:

$$1+r_{p,01}=\frac{X_1^A+X_1^B+X_1^C}{X_0^A+X_0^B+X_0^C}=\frac{150+120+90}{100+100+100}=\frac{360}{300}=\frac{12}{10}=1.2,$$

where $X_t^A,X_t^B,X_t^C$ are the net asset values at time $t$.  Next you calculate the growth factor of the second day of the portfolio, from time $1$ to time $2$:

$$1+r_{p,12}=\frac{X_2^A+X_2^B+X_2^C}{X_1^A+X_1^B+X_1^C}=\frac{150+120+60}{360}=\frac{330}{360}=\frac{11}{12}\approx 0.9167$$

Then the growth factor for the portfolio in two days is $1+r_{p,02}=(1+r_{p,01})\cdot (1+r_{p,12})$ $=\frac{12}{10}\cdot \frac{11}{12}=1.1$. Thus the growth rate of the portfolio in two days is $r_{p,02}=1.1-1=10\%$

And the average daily growth rate of the portfolio is $\sqrt{1+r_{p,02}}-1=\sqrt{1.1}-1\approx 4.88\%$

**Update**

The contribution (in percent) of asset A at day 1 to the return of the portfolio is $r_{A1}^c=\frac{150-100}{300}=\frac16=16.\overline 6\%\approx 16.7\%$

---

The contribution (in percent) of asset C at day 1 to the return of the portfolio is $r_{C1}^c=\frac{90-100}{300}=\frac{-1}{30}=-3.\overline 3\%\approx -3.3\%$

The contribution (in percent) of asset C at day 2 to the return of the portfolio is $r_{C2}^c=\frac{60-90}{360}=\frac{-1}{12}=-8.\overline 3\%\approx -8.3\%$

Finally the ontribution (in percent) of asset C from time $t=0$ to time $t=2$ to the return of the portfolio in that period is

$$(1+r_{C1}^c)\cdot (1+ r_{C2}^c)-1=\left(1-\frac{1}{30}
\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{12}\right)-1$$ $$\approx 0.9666666\cdot 0.9166666-1=-0.11388901444444\approx -11.4\%$$

$\underline{\textrm{Important to mention}}$: Consecutive growth rates $r_i$ of $n$ periods  are never summed up. You multiply the the growth factors $(q_i=1+r_i)$ and  subtract 1 to obtain the growth rate in $n$ periods:

$$r_{0,n}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (1+r_i)-1=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n q_i-1$$

Comment: Thank you @callculus and you have nearly answered my question. But the key part missing is how I can break that 4.88% daily growth rate (or the 10% growth rate over two days) into its components ie which stock contributed to the growth rate and which detracted. And importantly, the contributions of each stock should reconcile with the total number. For example, if the portfolio grew 10% over two days, 9% was from stock A, 5% was from stock B, and -4% was from stock C. So 1-%+9%-4% = 10% growth rate of the portfolio. That is the key question I need answered. How can we disaggregate the 10%?

Comment: The growth rate of he portfolio is not 10%. The growth rate is $\frac{109+105+96}{100+100+100}-1=\frac{310}{300}-1=3.33...\%$ Or you can calculate $$\frac{n+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n r_i}{n}-\frac{n}{n}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n r_i}{n}$$ $=\frac{0.09+0,05-0.04}{3}=\frac{0.1}{3}=3.33...\%$. This is a transformation of the first formula. Here you have the sum of the growth rates.

Comment: @calcullus thank you for getting back to me. but we were not struggling with calculating the return of the portfolio, but rather with how to reconcile the portfolio return with the stock level returns. How do you breakdown the portfolio return into its components of the different stocks. Your total return for the two day period for the portfolio is indeed 10%, with a 3.33% growth rate. But how do you break those numbers down by stock?????? That's what I'm interested in. you began with 300 and ended with 330, thats a 10% total return. What is the contribution to return of each stock?

Comment: @financeguru I´ve made an update. The numerical examples should explain it. You can check the other numbers as well.

Comment: You've shown that the contribution to return of C over time t=0 to time t=2 is equal to -11.4% which I agree with. By that same calculation, A's contribution over two days is 16.7% and B's contribution is 6.7%. Now, if you sum the three ie 16.7% + 6.7% -11.4% = 12%. But, over two days, we know that the portfolio returned only 10% as shown in your calculation above. This is my exact question! Why don't the two values reconcile, and what do we need to do to get them to reconcile?!?!